# ESC/POS printing barcode aligned vertically and horizontally in the middle?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

My code is currently printing a barcode and hri text easily, but I want everything to be printed dead centre on the label.  Can someone please tell me when I should declare the alignment command?
 I tried declaring it at the beginning and just before the barcode print command, but the barcode is still printing in the top left corner.
 
Here is my align command:

```
    def align_esc(self,esc,n):
        '''
        ESC|a|n
        0<=n<=2,48<=n<=50
        0,48 = Left; 1,49 = Mid; 2,50 = Right
        '''
        align = [esc,n]
        align_prnt = bytearray(align)
        return align
```

The reason I am not using escpos python library is because I am printing from an Android device.
Edit:
The above function is missing the following character on line 7:

```
align = [esc,97,n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [ESC a](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=58) command description of EPSON, there are the following notes.
Are these notices on the `ESC a` command for your printer?

> - When Standard mode is selected, this command is enabled only when processed at the beginning of the line in Standard mode.
> - The justification has no effect in Page mode.
> - This command executes justification in the print area set by `GS L` and `GS W`.
> - This command justifies printing data (**such as characters, all graphics, barcodes, and two-dimensional code**) and space area set by HT, `ESC $`, and `ESC \`.
> - Settings of this command are effective until `ESC @` is executed, the printer is reset, or the power is turned off.

Often, the `ESC a` command is specified not after the beginning of the line but after printing a few characters or spaces.

For example, if you print with plain text instead of a barcode and it is not centered, then `ESC a` is not specified at the beginning of the line.
Change the `ESC a` command so that it is specified at the beginning of the line.

However, if the plain text is printed centered, the feature may not work for barcodes.
In that case, contact the printer vendor to determine if barcode alignment is available and how to do so.
Or there is no automatic function, it may be a method to adjust the print position with `ESC \` etc.

---

The print position in the horizontal direction can be specified by either `ESC $` or `ESC \`.
Only the starting point of the calculation is different. `ESC $` is the left edge of the paper, and `ESC \` is the print position at that time.
You won't need to use `GS P`.

Comment: To answer your question:  The only notices in the Urovo K319 printing booklet is for your bullet 1 and bullet 4.  So I got the label to print in the vertical sort off centre of the label.  I noticed that my above ```ESC a``` command function was missing the "a" or 97 character.  But it isn't horizontally centre only sort off vertically.   There is a bigger space left of the printing than right of the printing.  How to I set the horizontal axis?  Is it the ```ESC $``` or ```ESC /``` or ```ESC P``` command or a combination of the three?